# Fastest NoSQL wildcard search DBMS?

Tags: mysql, database, go, web, nosql

This is not a subjective question. I'd like to know objectively, what is the fastest at searching both:

1. "search string" + wildcard
2. wildcard + "search string" + wildcard

Constraints:

- Limit to first 20 results (1 preferred over 2, aka run "search string" + wildcard before wc+ss+wc and only if 20 results not found for first)
- 100,000 rows in db (non-changing)

This database would be very heavily used for searching only. Trying to switch from MySQL to a single file that can be implemented more easily in an executable or towards mobile development. If MySQL servers can be packaged that would work too, but from what I can tell that is a whole complex mess of it's own.

Do these features exist in somewhat reasonable performance in any database not requiring a server? So far we are working with key value store and trying to create multiple databases to parse search queries, but obviously that takes up a lot of hard drive space.

With MySQL our queries are max 0.05s (best 0.03s) using an index. With Go's BoltDB Key=>Value we're hitting max of 3.5s (as it has to query every single key to check for a match) -- so if there is a way to decrease this greatly we're really interested in finding out!

Comment: the first can be done extremely fast by redis, but the second isn't (unless you re-index every suffix)

Comment: I'm pretty sure most key value no-SQL searches would be quite fast for the first scenario, it really is the second one that is causing trouble for us

Comment: since the data is so small, just create a redis sorted set with all the suffixes (i.e. if you have the word `hello`, insert `hello, ello, llo, lo, o`), and then search it with ZRANGEBYLEX. it's primitive but it will work.

Comment: yea, we tried this and it increased the database from around 50MB to 1+ GB. Perhaps we can re-try with some different methods... thank you as always :)